# Does Anyone know why my Camera size doesn't line up in with the Grid size on default???

Tags: unity-game-engine

So i've been having this problem for the last 2 days where my camera size isn't fitting my grid/tilemap size. Since i want to use tiles to make my game grid not fitting in the camera size would be really annoying because the tile would stick out of the camera view.[i attached an image where you could see the grid not lining up with the camera size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nst4Q.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please check follow settings:

1. Check your **Game** window resolution setting, dose it be changed? If you are using **Free Aspect**, the camera size also be changed with Game window size in Editor.
2. Check the **Feld of View** setting of your camera.